# Cont'd Decimal Expansion, rational or not?

Tags: decimal-expansion

This is a follow up from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/505017/is-the-number-0-112358132134-rational-or-irrational).

Since it's proven by Calvin Lin that $0.11235813213455...$ (Fibonacci Sequence), I'm not wondering if the sequence $$0.123456789101112131415...$$

(which is just natural numbers) is rational or not.  Thanks for the help in advanced!

Comment: The decimal expansion does not terminate or repeat, so the number is not rational.

Comment: This is the Champernowne constant. It is known to be transcendental.

Comment: it's even normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number is rational if and only if its decimal expansion terminates or eventually begins repeating. This number does neither.

Comment: Thanks again for the again!

Comment: You can actually leave off the "terminates" option since it is included in the "eventually begins repeating" option. For example, $\frac14=0.250000\cdots$. Repeating doesn't preclude that the repeating part is the digit zero. So: A number is rational if and only if its decimal expansion eventually repeats. (And there's nothing special about "decimal" here. Any integral base $>1$ will do.) Also, if you don't like repeating zeroes, you can always rewrite such a case with repeating nines: $0.250000\cdots \equiv 0.249999\cdots$. +1 for you.